# C compiler for 8086 or other 16-bit target

Tags: software-development, c, emulator, compiler, embedded-systems

I'm looking for a C cross-compiler and emulator for a **16-bit** processor that runs under Linux. I'd prefer for the target to be 8086 with FreeDOS or on Dosemu (then finding an emulator is not a problem). One limiting factor is that it needs to support 64-bit arithmetic.

The goal is to port and test some code that currently targets 32-bit embedded systems to 16-bit systems for which I don't have easy access development tools and emulators. The code is mostly portable apart from currently assuming that `int` is 32-bit, so any 16-bit target will do for the continuous integration testing.

The constraints:

- The compiler and the emulator must run under Linux, in an automated build and test environment.
- In the emulator, I need to be able to run my program and get data in and out. I would need either a basic OS, or some code to link into my program to implement serial or file I/O (ideally both but as long as I have a way to provide the test data and retrieve the results it should be fine). DOS (on 8086) would be nice because there's existing tooling around it, but it isn't a requirement.
- The software should be free to run. A license that doesn't allow redistributing the binaries produced by the compiler would be ok (I only need the binaries for internal testing). A license that prohibits all commercial use wouldn't work for me right now (although I might get a purchase approval later).
- The compiler needs to support the following features:

  - 8-bit `char`
  - **16-bit `int`**
  - Ideally C99, but if not then at least **64-bit integers** (`uint64_t`).
  - The better the warnings about integer sizes the better, since this is code that hadn't been written for a 16-bit target in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Watcom C/C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watcom_C/C%2B%2B) ([old website](http://openwatcom.org/), [v2 fork](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2) supports 16-bit x86 targets including DOS. It can produce executables that run in Dosbox. It's free. It supports C (up to C99, at least including `stdint.h` and `long long`), C++ and Fortran.

I ended up using this for my project, but only for a short length of time because I ended up gaining access to the real target platform soon after. So I can't comment on the extensiveness of its warnings.